# After appending some Content to Parent Div,Content not appending to Child Div using .html of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had added a div to 'parent of share button', and then i tried to append some span to 'share button'

**1.** `$("#ShareBtn").parent().html("\\ i had appended some div code here");`

**2.** `$('#ShareBtn').html("\\some more code i added here");`

but first action is successful,second one is failing..

can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call would delete the #ShareBtn since jquery .html() replace all the elements contained inside the element, you would want to use .append() instead.

This is what's happening:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="shareBtn"></div>
</div>
```

after you run this line

```
$("#ShareBtn").parent().html("\\ i had appended some div code here");
```

the element would look like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  \\ i had appended some div code here
</div>
```

rendering the second line of code useless since the element ShareBtn doesn't exists anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that `$.html();` in jQuery doesn't append code, but replaces the innerHTML (see Javascript) of an element. In you code `$('#ShareBtn')` doesn't exist anymore after overwriting its parent content.